# django cms menu: display page title alongside the page's menu title

Tags: django-cms

I want to display a plain django-cms menu. I override the default `menu/menu.html` template, as I want to display the page's title, alongside the page's menu title. This is for a content navigation, where the additional info of the title is useful.

The default is (in the `<a></a>`):

`{{ child.get_menu_title }}`.

What I want is

`{{ child.get_menu_title }}<span>{{ child.the_page_title }}</span>`

But, somehow, I cant display the title alongside the menu_title. If the field `menu_title` is set, it overrides the `title` attribute of the `NavigationNode`, and it is returned when calling `get_menu_title` (obviously). Also, the title is not in the `attr` ([NavigationNode attr](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/navigation.html#menus.base.NavigationNode.attr)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ended using

```
{% load cms_tags %} {% page_attribute 'title' child.id %}
```

This might not be ideal concerning performance, but works very well. Open but for better solutions!

Comment: class `NavigationNode` in the code is very limited. I'm also going to be with this solution.